# What is the difference between residual sum of squares and ordinary least squares?

Tags: linear-regression

They look like the same thing to me but I'm not sure.

Update: in retrospect, this was not a very good question. OLS refers to fitting a line to data and RSS is the cost function that OLS uses. It finds the parameters that gives the **least** residual sum of **square** errors. It is called **ordinary** in OLS refers to the fact that we are doing a linear fit.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a [definition from **Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares):

> In statistics, the residual sum of squares (RSS) is the sum of the
>   squares of residuals. It is a measure of the discrepancy between the
>   data and an estimation model; Ordinary least squares (OLS) is a method
>   for estimating the unknown parameters in a linear regression model,
>   with the goal of minimizing the differences between the observed
>   responses in some arbitrary dataset and the responses predicted by the
>   linear approximation of the data.

So RSS is a **measure** of how good the model approximates the data while OLS is a **method** of constructing a good model.

Comment: You have no idea how helpful your answer is!

Answer (score 5):

> Ordinary least squares (OLS)

Ordinary least squares (OLS) is the workhorse of statistics. It gives a way of taking complicated outcomes and explaining behaviour (such as trends) using linearity. The simplest application of OLS is fitting a line.

> Residuals

Residuals are the observable errors from the estimated coefficients. In a sense, the residuals are estimates of the errors.

Let's explain the things using `R` code:

First fit a ordinary least square line of diamond datasets in `UsingR` library:

```
library(UsingR)
data("diamond")
y <- diamond$price
 x <- diamond$carat
n <- length(y)
olsline <- lm(y ~ x)
plot(x, y,
     main ="Odinary Least square line",
     xlab = "Mass (carats)", 
     ylab = "Price (SIN $)", 
     bg = "lightblue", 
     col = "black", cex = 2, pch = 21,frame = FALSE)
abline(olsline, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Now, Let's calculate the residual i.e residual sum of squares:
   In `R` you can easily calculate the residual as `resid(olsline)`, for visualisation let's calculate it manually:

```
# The residuals from R method
e <- resid(olsline)
## Obtain the residuals manually, get the predicated Ys first
yhat <- predict(olsline)
# The residuals are y -yhat, Let's check by comparing this with R's build in resid function
ce <- y - yhat
max(abs(e-ce))
## Let's do it again hard coding the calculation of Yhat
max(abs(e- (y - coef(olsline)[1] - coef(olsline)[2] * x)))
# Residuals arethe signed length of the red lines
plot(diamond$carat, diamond$price,
    main ="Residuals sum of (actual Y - predicted Y)^2",
     xlab = "Mass (carats)", 
     ylab = "Price (SIN $)", 
     bg = "lightblue", 
     col = "black", cex = 2, pch = 21,frame = FALSE)
abline(olsline, lwd = 2)
for (i in 1 : n) 
  lines(c(x[i], x[i]), c(y[i], yhat[i]), col = "red" , lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Hope these visualization will clear your doubts between **RSS** & **OLS**

Comment: Reference: [Coursera Regression Models class](https://www.coursera.org/learn/regression-models/), I have recently completed it.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, OLS is a model to estimate the regression line based on training data. While, RSS is a parameter to know the accuracy of model for both testing and training data.